# Haproxy SSL termination : Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused"

Tags: haproxy, kubernetes-ingress, haproxy-ingress

I was trying to implement SSL termination with HAProxy.

This is how my haproxy.cfg looks like

```
frontend Local_Server
    bind *:443 ssl crt /home/vagrant/ingress-certificate/k8s.pem
    mode tcp
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend k8s_server

backend k8s_server
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    server web1 100.0.0.2:8080 check
```

I have generated the self signed certificate which k8s.pem.

My normal URL **(without https)** is working perfectly fine .i.e. - http://100.0.0.2/hello

But when i try to access the same url with **HTTPS** .i.e.- https://100.0.0.2/hello i get 404 and when i checked my haproxy logs i can see following message

```
Jul 21 18:10:19 node1 haproxy[10813]: Server k8s_server/web1 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
Jul 21 18:10:19 node1 haproxy[10813]: Server k8s_server/web1 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

Any suggestions which i can incorporate in my haproxy.cfg ?

PS - The microservice which i am trying to access is deployed under kubernetes cluster with service exposed as ClusterIP

Comment: Which version of HAProxy do you use? The message is clear. HAProxy can reach the server `100.0.0.2:8080`. What's the ouput of `curl -v --max-time 5 https://100.0.0.2:8080/`?

Comment: I am using - HA-Proxy version 1.8.8-1ubuntu0.11 2020/06/22
Here is the console output of - curl -v --max-time 5 https://100.0.0.2:8080/
*   Trying 100.0.0.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 100.0.0.2 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 100.0.0.2 port 8080: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 100.0.0.2 port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: Well that's now clear why HAProxy can't connect to the server `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 100.0.0.2 port 8080: Connection refused `. You should fix this on the server `100.0.0.2:8080`

Comment: I will check whats wrong with the server